# Tumblr theme has a set avatar

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr, avatar

This might be a silly question, but I'm still pretty new at CSS and HTML, so I apologize in advance. 
I recently changed my tumblr theme, based on a code that I found online. It worked nicely, however it came with its own avatar, and won't display mine. I wouldn't mind this, but the one that comes with the code isn't cute at all :( I looked for the piece of code that would have the fill-in avatar, but I couldn't find it. If someone could help, that would be wonderful!

```
here is the original code 
[1]
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code. I don't thin "here is the orignial code" is all you have. And DON'T link to external site. Post your code on SO by editing your question

Comment: Yeah. We need to see the code..

Answer (score 3):

Search in your theme for "portrait" or "avatar" and you might see it. The avatar code is usually near the description so you could try searching for "description" as well.

This code will display your avatar image if you have one set.

```
 <img src="{PortraitURL-128}" alt="Portrait image" />
```

If you want a different size avatar, you can change the number "128" to 12, 24, 30, 40, 48, 64 or 96 — like this:

```
<img src="{PortraitURL-48}" alt="Portrait image" />
```

128 is the highest you can go, which is the biggest (128-pixels by 128-pixels.)